# gnuplot histogram: line 0: Too many columns in using specification

Tags: bash, plot, gnuplot, histogram

I want to create a histogram of a file that contains :

```
1 144 12.54
2 564 02.34
3 231 01.23
4 452 07.12
```

and what I use for that purpose in my script is :

```
gnuplot << EOF
            set terminal gif
            set terminal postscript eps color enhanced
            set output "diagramma";
            set title 'Diagramma'
            set key off
            set style data histogram
            set style histogram cluster gap 1
            set style fill solid border -1
            set boxwidth 0.9
            set autoscale
            set xlabel "May"
            plot 'finalsumfile' using 1:2 with histogram, 'finalsumfile' using 1:3 with histogram

EOF
```

So I want the first column as x coordinate and the second and third columns as y.

BUT when I run my script occurs this error:

```
line 0: Too many columns in using specification
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
 plot 'finalsumfile' using 2:xticlabels(1) with histogram
```

Histograms typically only take 1 column of data, which the "x-value" being implicitly incremented by one each time starting from 0.  To set explicit x labels, you need to use `xticlabels` which takes the string in the given column and uses that as the label.